# Struts2 redirecting to same page, but keep content of a form

Tags: jsp, struts2, internationalization

I'm using the Struts2 framework with +Java and JSP.

On every jsp page there are 3 buttons to switch the users locale (English, French, Dutch). I use the i18n method and then redirect the user to same page where he was before he clicked on one of the language buttons. **This works** fine, but because I'm using an action (with a result of type redirect), the page is loaded again (obviously, else the text wouldn't be updated to reflect the chosen language)

My problem is the following: If a user was filling in a long form and then mid-way decided to switch his language by clicking on one of the language button, the entire form is reset because the page was reloaded.

What I need: a clean solution to keep the fields in the form already filled in by the user. So the input labels would update (for example change from "username:" to the french "identifiant:") but the text the user entered there would just stay. I was thinking off an elaborate scheme to store all data a user enters in hidden inputs, and give this as parameter to the "change locale action". When the page reloads, all parameters will be fetched and filled in again. Considering the length and complexity of my form, this is a tedious task. Any suggestions?

Comment: The perfect solution could be if the user could change the language by staying on the page.

Comment: Do not show the switch buttons in the entry form, What you can do is ask the user for choose the language in home page and then navigate into your form.

Comment: You could automatically save inputted data behind the scene and show it on page reload.

Answer (score 0):

1. What you are thinking is fine, but have you checked other sites. I'm sure they doesn't implement such a thing, that's just because it's the users' choice if he wishes to do something like that. Just because we consider something a solution, doesn't mean that it's followed by most.
2. Another good option, is to prevent showing the language buttons on form-pages.